# Dealing with sequences in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, sequences, contour

I have 2 sequences. One (lets call this cvSeq x), which contains a number of contours (derived from cvFindContours) and a second (lets call this cvSeq y) which I have used cvCreateSeq upon, but doesn't actually have anything in it. I am looping through all the contours in x, and if a contour meets specific criteria, I add it to y. I am able to do the looping, but I don't know how to add an contour in x to y if it meets the criteria.

Does anyone know how to add a contour in a sequence to another sequence (that is empty)? Code examples will be appreciated.

PS: cvStartFindContours is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to use the C++ interface, instead of the old one. It is much simpler to use. Contours are stored as `vector<vector<Point>>`

You can use it in a similar way:

```
Mat myImg = (Mat)myIplImage;
//or better
Mat myImg = imread("image.jpg");

vector<vector<Point>> contours;

cv::findContours(myImg, contours,...);
```

Now access to contours and points is much simpler and easier

**Note** I did not checked the code accuracy. You must verify the correct way to send params to findContours, and all the rest.

Comment: Thank You. Just one more question - you said that contours are stored as vector<vector<Point>>. Would this still apply to a single contour? Wouldn't that be stored as vector<Point> ?

Comment: It should be stored in the same way the other contours are stored. So the vector containing contours will have size()==1.